# Django Rest Framework Serialize Model into Object with Custom Key

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, list, django-rest-framework

I am working with Django and djangorestframework. I know to serialize models into list of objects but I currently want to serialize them into an object with a custom key. For this instance, I want to serialize the user model into an object of objects which its acces key is the user's username.

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username']
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import UserSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

current output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "username_a"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "username_b"
    }
]
```

desired output:

```
{
    "username_a": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "username_b": {
        "id": 2
    }
}
```

alternative desired output:

```
{
    "username_a": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "username_a"
    },
    "username_b": {
        "id": 2
        "username": "username_b"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work to get the "alternative desired output":

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        list_of_objects = serializer.data
        object_of_objects = {}
        custom_key = "username"
        for current_object in list_of_objects:
            object_of_objects[current_object[custom_key]] = current_object
        return Response(object_of_objects)
```